# R write text at specific location in a dataframe

Tags: r, dataframe

I have a dataframe with data over 482 days, and for each day I have 224 values, which makes it a dataframe with a length of 107'968. Now I want to add before every day a text corresponding to that exact day.

I know that this can't be done in a dataframe, I also tried it with a list but I couldn't figure out how I should approach this problem.

My dataframe looks similar to this:

```
Layer    Row     Column    Shead    Ehead
1        1       1         40.1     40.4
1        1       2         40.3     40.5
1        1       3         40.2     40.6

1        1       1         40.4     40.2
1        1       2         40.5     40.3
1        1       3         40.6     40.7

1        1       1         40.2     40.4
1        1       2         40.3     40.4
1        1       3         40.7     40.8
```

Here I made for one day 3 values and this over 3 days. As I said before, the real data is over 482 days and 224 values for each day. But if it works with this data then it should also work with the bigger data.

And now my goal is to reach this:

```
Layer    Row     Column    Shead    Ehead
3  0 -- 5. ITMP NP. Stress Period 1
1        1       1         40.1     40.4
1        1       2         40.3     40.5
1        1       3         40.2     40.6

3  0 -- 5. ITMP NP. Stress Period 2
1        1       1         40.4     40.2
1        1       2         40.5     40.3
1        1       3         40.6     40.7

3  0 -- 5. ITMP NP. Stress Period 3   
1        1       1         40.2     40.4
1        1       2         40.3     40.4
1        1       3         40.7     40.8
```

Where the first value of the text belongs to the number of values per period/day and the second value has to be zero. The period number at the end should go up for each day.

I want my dataframe to look like that because I want it to read in a Groundwater-flow-simulation software (Processing Modflow X) and in order to read the values in there has to be the right text before every day.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is one solution:

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
library(tibble)
library(magrittr)

#Data
#Shead and Ehead are just random decimal values affixed to "40" here.
df <- data.frame(Layer = rep_len(1, 9),
                 Row = rep_len(1, 9),
                 Column = rep(c(1:3), 3),
                 Shead = as.numeric(paste0(40, ".", seq(1:9))),
                 Ehead = as.numeric(paste0(40, ".", seq(9:1))))

#How many rows we have per group
perg <- 3

#How many groups (i.e., days in your case) we have in total
totg <- 3

#We need to create some sort of grouping variable
df$Group <- rep(1:totg, each = perg)

#Adding an empty row first
df %<>% group_by(Group) %>%
  do(add_row(., .before = 0))

#Resetting the grouping variable to accommodate the extra row per group
df$Group <- rep(1:totg, each = perg+1)

#Adding the string
df %<>% group_by(Group) %>%
  mutate(Layer = ifelse(is.na(Layer), paste0(perg, " 0 -- 5. ITMP NP. Stress Period ", Group), as.character(Layer)))

#Removing the NAs
df <- as.data.frame(df)
df[is.na(df)] <- ""

#Dropping the grouping column
df %<>% select(-Group)

df

#                                 Layer Row Column Shead Ehead
# 1  3 0 -- 5. ITMP NP. Stress Period 1                       
# 2                                   1   1      1  40.1  40.1
# 3                                   1   1      2  40.2  40.2
# 4                                   1   1      3  40.3  40.3
# 5  3 0 -- 5. ITMP NP. Stress Period 2                       
# 6                                   1   1      1  40.4  40.4
# 7                                   1   1      2  40.5  40.5
# 8                                   1   1      3  40.6  40.6
# 9  3 0 -- 5. ITMP NP. Stress Period 3                       
# 10                                  1   1      1  40.7  40.7
# 11                                  1   1      2  40.8  40.8
# 12                                  1   1      3  40.9  40.9
```

What this code does is first add rows containing `NA`s every `perg` number of rows. Then it writes in the string you've asked for into the `Layer` column using the values from `perg` and `Group` respectively. It then removes all NAs from the `data.frame`.

You'll have to change `perg` to `224` and `totg` to `482` to make this work with your data. Additionally, as the `NA`s have been replaced with blanks, when you're writing the data to a file, you should NOT use space (`\s` or anything equivalent) as a separator.

Answer (score 1):

sapply create a `list` of your `df`

```
list_df <- sapply(df[1:10,1],list)
```

`lapply` uses a anonymous functions to use paste with a temp var `x` to access the first value of the `list_df` and write `"datehere"` and store in the list final, lapply also returns a list.

```
list_final <- lapply(list_df, function(x) paste0("datehere",x[[1]]))
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but it didnt quite work on my data. I edited my question now, so I would be glad if you take another look at it.